# iPad/iPhone google maps mash up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps, ipad

I would like to create my own google maps mash up exactly like wundermaps but with different data.

How can i go about doing this?

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wundermap/id364884105?mt=8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple have a sample project called Weather map that shows exactly what you are after.
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/WeatherMap/Introduction/Intro.html